# Why JSDOM changes the html structure?

Tags: javascript, html, jsdom

Here is the code

```js
var fs = require('fs')
var htmlSource = fs.readFileSync("public/html/index.html", "utf8")
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;
const dom = new JSDOM(htmlSource);
htmlSource = dom.window.document.querySelector("html").outerHTML
console.log(htmlSource)
```

```html
<!-- This is a public/html/index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>Home Electricity Manager</title> 
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1 id="the-header">Wellcome to home electricity manager!</h1>
    <div add-row ng-controller="myController" style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;">
        <span style="white-space:pre;">Button text</span><br/>
        <button id="first-button" ng-style="myStyle" ng-click="toggleRelay()" id="switch-cirquit-1">{{ButtonStatus}}</button>
    </div>
    <div add-row ng-controller="myController" style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;">   
        <span id="second-button" style="white-space:pre;">{{buttonOneText}}</span><br/>
        <button ng-style="myStyle" ng-click="toggleRelay()" id="switch-cirquit-1">{{ButtonStatus}}</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="postController" style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;">
        <button ng-click="post()">{{buttonName}}</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

 <!-- src="js/directives/add-row.js" -->
```

And the result form the line `console.log(htmlSource)` is:

```html
<html><head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

    <title>Home Electricity Manager</title> 
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1 id="the-header">Wellcome to home electricity manager!</h1>
    <div add-row="" ng-controller="myController" style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;">
        <span style="white-space:pre;">Button text</span><br>
        <button id="first-button" ng-style="myStyle" ng-click="toggleRelay()">{{ButtonStatus}}</button>
    </div>
    <div add-row="" ng-controller="myController" style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;">    
        <span id="second-button" style="white-space:pre;">{{buttonOneText}}</span><br>
        <button ng-style="myStyle" ng-click="toggleRelay()" id="switch-cirquit-1">{{ButtonStatus}}</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="postController" style="text-align: center; display: inline-block;">
        <button ng-click="post()">{{buttonName}}</button>
    </div>



 </body></html>
```

Please note that the `script` elements are moved from `<html>` children to `<head>` children. This happened automatically. Moreover some new lines seems to be added to the newly created dom file. Please see the difference between the two html files. Why is that change?

Comment: Per the spec, the only tags allowed as direct children of an `html` element are `head` and `body`.

Comment: `script` inside `html` isn't valid HTML.

Comment: It's invalid HTML to have scripts floating around as direct children of `<html>`. It probably does some simple validation checks, such as adding empty values to your directive attributes.

Comment: Since `<head>` isn't rendered, newlines between elements have no effect and are not in the DOM. `outerHTML` is simply adding newlines in useful places.

Answer (score 1):

*In general*, turning an HTML serialization into a DOM tree, and serializing the resulting tree won't guarantee that the final serialization will be identical to the original one. This is true whether or not your HTML is conforming to the specification.

However, in your specific case, your HTML does not conform to the structure specified by the standard. When a conforming parser runs into non-conforming HTML, it has a series of steps it must follow to resolve the problem. This is effectively an attempt to make sense of the non-conforming HTML on the fly. In your case the sequence is this:

1. Start in the `initial` parsing mode,
2. Move to `before html` mode when encountering `DOCTYPE`.
3. Move to `before head` mode when encountering `<html>`.
4. Insert a `head` element and move to `in head` when encountering `script`.

The last step enumerated above is where the browser modifies your document structure to make it conform. If you check the [rules](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#the-before-head-insertion-mode) in the specification, you see that encountering a `script` element while in the `before head` mode matches the "Anything else" rule, which results in appending a `head` element to the DOM tree and moving to the `in head` mode. The `script` element is then reprocessed in the `in head` mode and is just added to the newly created `head` element.

When the parser runs into the `<head>` tag you put in your HTML file, this tag is just ignored because the parser is already in the `in head` mode, due to the earlier `script` elements.

---

The spacing you get is from applying the rules from the specification. To point out a few salient cases:

1. There is no newline before `<head>` because any space in `before head` mode is ignored.
2. There's no newline after `<head>` either because when the parser created a `head` element to fix your HTML, it did not insert a newline with it. (It's just not part of the rules.)
3. The blank line you see before `<title>` in the serialization is made up of the newlines that appeared before and after `<head>` in your original HTML. The parser ignored your `<head>` tag (as explained above), but it kept the spacing that was around it.